# Is it possible to insert List of custom class objects via ContentValue into sqlite database? Are there any fast enough alternatives for that?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am developing android application.
I have large amount of sophisticated data that I get from the server. At first login I had to insert all the data into local sqlite database. I found saving via ContentValues as the fastest method but I have a problem with custom classess.

```
for (final CustomClass r : myObjects) {

 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("ID", r.getId());
Cache.OpenDatabase().insert("Database",null,values);
}

class CustomClass {
int id;
ClassB my_class;
List<ClassC> my_list;
}
```

What is the best way to insert that kind of data into a sqlite database? That for loop turns around 1000 times.  Please give me some hints!

Comment: switch to the new persitence api Room https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/7-steps-to-room-27a5fe5f99b2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support saving objects directly everything has to be stored as either an INTEGER(up to 64 Bit signed, so int and long), TEXT (String), REAL (8 byte IEEE floating point), NULL or a BLOB (byte array).

There are extensions, such as [ROOM](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) that are basically wrappers (abstraction layer) around SQLite that simplify object handling.

However, could speed up your for loop by embedding the loop in a transaction along the lines of :-

```
SQLiteDatabase db = Cache.OpenDatabase(); //<<<<<<<<<< Outside of the loop as only needed once
db.beginTransaction();
for (final CustomClass r : myObjects) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("ID", r.getId());
    db.insert("Database",null,values);
}
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

Comment: I was using sth like ROOM api but it was so slow. Content Values are much faster it is around 7 second difference. With Content Values it takes 3,5-4seconds. All in all, I will try again with ROOM api and let you know! Thank you for your tips !